# Date difference based on yyymm in unix

Tags: shell, unix

```
#####DATE1=201609
#### DATE2=201508
```

How to calculate the difference between these two date and get output as count of no of month
ie

```
201609-201508=13month
```

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of the time difference is generally a complicated task, even for a single calendar type (and there are [many](http://www.tondering.dk/claus/calendar.html)). Many programming languages have a built-in support for date and time manipulation operations, including calculation of the time difference. But the most useful feature available in the popular shells is the [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) command which lacks this feature, unfortunately.

Therefore, we should whether write a script in another language, or make some assumptions such as the number of days in the year.

For example, in Perl the task is done with just four lines of code:

```
perl -e $(cat <<'PerlScript'
use Time::Piece;
my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime($ARGV[0], '%Y%m');
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime($ARGV[1], '%Y%m');
printf "%d months\n", ($t1 - $t2)->months;
PerlScript
) 201609 201508
```

However, the difference of `Time::Piece` objects is an instance of [`Time::Seconds`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) which actually assumes that

> there are 24 hours in a day, 7 days in a week, 365.24225 days in a
>   year and 12 months in a year.

which indirectly confirms my words regarding the complexity of the task.

Then let's make the same assumption, and write a simple *shell* script:

```
DATE1=201609
DATE2=201508

printf '(%d - %d) / 2629744.2\n' \
  $(date -d ${DATE1}01 +%s) \
  $(date -d ${DATE2}01 +%s) | bc
```

where `2629744.2` is the number of seconds in month, i.e. `3600 * 24 * (365.24225 / 12)`.

Note, most of the shells do not support floating point arithmetic. That's why we need to invoke external tools such as `bc`.

The script outputs `13`. This is a portable version. You may run it in the standard shell, Bash, Korn shell, or Zsh, for instance. If you want to put the result into a variable, just wrap the `printf` command in `$( ... )`:

```
months=$(printf '(%d - %d) / 2629744.2\n' \
  $(date -d ${DATE1}01 +%s) \
  $(date -d ${DATE2}01 +%s) | bc)

printf '%d - %d = %d months\n' $DATE1 $DATE2 $months
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution -

```
[vipin@hadoop ~]$ cat time.awk
{
diff1=((substr($1,1,4)) - (substr($2,1,4)))
diff2=((substr($1,5,2)) - (substr($2,5,2)))
if(diff1 > 0)
        {
        if(diff2 > 0)
                {
                print (diff1+diff2)
                }
        else if (diff2 = 0)
                {
                print (diff1+diff2)
                }
                else
                {
                diff2=(12+((substr($1,5,2)-(substr($2,5,2)))))
                diff1=(diff1-1)
                print (diff1+diff2)
                }
        }
else if(diff1 == 0)
        {
        if(diff2 > 0)
                {
                print (diff1+diff2)
                }
        else if (diff2 == 0)
                {
                print (diff1+diff2)
                }
        else
                {
                 print "Argument 2 is greater than 1"
                }
        }
else
        {
        print "Argument 2 is greater than 1"
        }
}
```

> Test Cases -

```
[vipin@hadoop ~]$ cat time1.txt && awk -f time.awk time1.txt
201611 201601
10
[vipin@hadoop ~]$ cat time2.txt && awk -f time.awk time2.txt
201601 201611
Argument 2 is greater than 1
[vipin@hadoop ~]$ cat time3.txt && awk -f time.awk time3.txt
201511 201601
Argument 2 is greater than 1
[vipin@hadoop ~]$ cat time4.txt && awk -f time.awk time4.txt
201611 201611
0
```

Comment: oldest_year_month_temp=201602

NUM_PART_RETAIN=20

oldest_year_month=`date --date="$(oldest_year_month_temp +%Y%m) - $NUM_PART_RETAIN month" "+%Y%m` how to get 20 month old value

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something quick and dirty that won't work for **all** months in history, but it's probably good enough: convert YYYYMM to the number of months since year 0:

```
$ ym2m() { 
    if [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$ ]]; then 
        echo $(( 10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]} * 12 + 10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ))
    else 
        return 1
    fi
}

$ ym2m 201609
24201

$ ym2m 201508
24188

$ echo $(( $(ym2m 201609) - $(ym2m 201508) ))
13
```

Notes:

- requires bash version 4.3 (I think)
- `ym2m` => "year-month to months"
- uses `10#number` in the arithmetic expression to ensure "08" and "09" are not treated as invalid octal numbers.